# WPF - Prevent scaling of Image control + getting Actual Height

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Just recently I switched my Windows to 125% DPI scaling mode and found out that my app does things that I don't want it to do.

One of the problems is scaling of the image I am showing in the app. Let's assume it can be any image and for this example let it be a 600-pixel wide one. I want it to stay just like that. I'm ok with scaling the rest of the interface but this one particular Image control has to be exactly as wide as the Image is, and not scaled up to 125% (to 750 pixels). How can I achieve that? Should I change control size after some DPI-related event fires?

Also, the second question is, why WPF is lying to me? When I get ActualWidth it tells me 600 pixels, but Paintbrush isn't lying - I hope - and it shows 750 pixels when I measure width on the screenshot. Should I be checking this value after any particular event so that I get an actual ActualWidth?

Some code:

```
imgNav.Source = ImageManager.LoadBitmapImage(uri);
BitmapImage bimp = imgNav.Source;
imgNav.Height = bimp.PixelHeight;
imgNav.Width = bimp.PixelWidth;
...
txtFoo.Text = imgNav.ActualWidth.ToString();
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: WPF doesn't measure in pixels. The ActualWidth is `the element's width, as a value in device-independent units` (see [Remarks section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx)). See also the *About Resolution and Device-Independent Graphics* section in the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) article on MSDN. So actually WPF isn't "lying to you". It's just your expectation being wrong.

Comment: Ok, I read it and admit this makes sense - now I get it why it's giving me those strange numbers. I am now recalculating size of the control on the fly, after getting monitor's DPI, but it's far from elegant solution I would wish to, so I am leaving this question open. Thank you for the link.